# Can the Chinese trackpad handwriting input method be used with a graphics tablet?

Tags: trackpad, input-source

On Macs with a multitouch trackpad, I'm told that from the Input Sources options you can select the option to draw Chinese and Japanese characters.

I have a Mac Mini, and a Wacom multitouch graphics tablet/trackpad, and I'd quite like to be able to use this, but the option just isn't there. I'm thinking I might be able to make it show up by editing a plist file somewhere, but I'm really not sure where to look -- my peering at various files in `~/Library/Preferences` and `/Library/Preferences` didn't turn up anything that looked relevant.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to make it show up in the options?

Comment: I think Apple's Chinese handwriting input only works with its own hardware.  An alternative is at http://www.yale.edu/chinesemac/pages/input_methods.html#PenPower For Wacom, you probably need to ask them.

Comment: The enabled input sources are stored in `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.HIToolbox.*.plist`. I don't have a trackpad or a graphics tablet, but can someone who has a trackpad copy the entry for com.apple.inputmethod.ChineseHandwriting in the AppleEnabledInputSources dictionary?

Comment: PS All my searches seem to indicate there is no way to do it with a Wacom device, but if you know Chinese you might try the new Apple Chinese forums at https://discussionschinese.apple.com/

Comment: This question is rather old, but today I was asking myself the very same question and came across this: https://tenonedesign.com/inklet.php